# WordPress login page returns 404 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, authentication, load, admin

I have WordPress site. All are running well. 
But problem is when I am going to access admin panel by typing http://cricketmatchreports.com/wp-admin
it returns errors like following:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Before 2 hrs I was able to enter login page. I also don't make any change.

Please help.
Now how can I solve this

Comment: As stackoverflow is primarily for programming questions, you may have more success with this kind of question on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I have tried a lot from stack overflow, exchange. But I am unable to solve this problem.

Comment: There's just not enough information to figure it out. I'm not sure you COULD give enough information. This is going to require some debugging. Hire a DevOps person to help you figure it out. (Or delete WordPress and re-install. If you've only had it up 2 hours, that may be the easiest way to solve it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WordPress is running out of a subdirectory (`cricket`) (have you recently changed your WordPress URL or Site URL?).  You need to include the subdirectory in the URL.  Try http://cricketmatchreports.com/cricket/wp-admin